# DrawFocusRect function

Tags: image, delphi, selection

In a picture, I want to draw a selection area with a circular shape. I used to draw rectangular shape but never dealt with any other. Is it possible to be done ?  I am coding in Delphi

Comment: Welcome, Have you tried anything so far? Please provide information such as what have you tried so far and post your code for users to help you the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DrawFocusRect()` supports rectangles only.  For other shapes, you will have to manually draw them yourself as desired, such as with `Ellipse()` with an appropriate `Brush` and `Pen`.

To have similar appearance and behavior with [`DrawFocusRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect), use an [alternating](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPenStyle) and [XOR](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPenMode) pen. E.g.:

```
var
  Brush: TLogBrush;
begin
  Brush.lbStyle := BS_SOLID;
  Brush.lbColor := clBlack;
  Canvas.Pen.Handle := ExtCreatePen(PS_COSMETIC or PS_ALTERNATE, 1, Brush, 0, nil);
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psAlternate;
  Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNotXor;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Ellipse(...
```